# what's wrong in my python code? i'm unable to get any output.?

Tags: python

I'm unable to understand what is wrong in my code why I'm not getting any output?
I have checked my code thoroughly but still, I'm unable to find any error.
when I try to run it on pycharm it doesn't do anything.

```
import random
    def ques():
        name=input("What's your name?:")
        print("Hi",name,"!")
    
        choice=random.choice("+x")
        finish=False
        quesno=0
        correctques=0
    
        while finish == False:
            if quesno<10|questno>=0:
                no1=random.randrange(1,10)
                no2=random.randrange(1,10)
                print((no1),(choice),(no2))
                ans=int(input("What's the answer?:"))
                quesno=quesno+1
    
                if choice==("+"):
                    realans=no1+no2
                    if ans==realans:
                        print("That's the correct answer!")
                        correctques=correctques+1
                    else:
                        print("That's incorrect!,the answer was",realans,"!")
    
            if choice==("x"):
                realans=no1*no2
                if ans==realans:
                    print("That's the correct answer!")
                    correctques=correctques+1
                else:
                    print("That's incorrect!,the answer was",realans,"!")
    
            elif choice==("-"):
                realans=no1-no2
                if ans==realans:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctques=correctques+1
                else:
                     print("That's incorrect!,the answer was",realans,"!")
            else:
                finish=True
        else:
             print("Good Job",name,"! You have finished the quiz")
```

Comment: On line 12, you should be using `or` instead of `|`. (`|` is a bitwise OR operator which probably isn't what you're intending to use)

Comment: @Edric Don't you mean `or`?   `if quesno<10 or questno>=0:`  Also, I assume `questno` should be `quesno`.  In that case you could even do `if 0 <= quesno < 10:`

Comment: Do you ever call `ques`?

Comment: `if quesno<10|questno>=0:` should be `if quesno<10 or questno>=0:`. `|` is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: Do you get any output whatsoever? Like, do you get the `What's your name?` prompt? Also, you have `ques()` in your code somewhere, right? You have to actually call the function to run it, you can't just define it and expect it to be executed.

Comment: To expand on @Carcigenicate's comment - you define a function with all of your logic in it, but you never actually *call* the function to execute it. Simply add a line with `ques()` on the last line of your file and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks guys, it was just a silly mistake :) solved using" or"

Comment: @AbdullahAhmadKhan You can even simplify the `or` to `if 0 <= quesno < 10:` :-)

Comment: thank you guys for helping me so fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you run it? add this to the end of your code

```py
ques()
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ques()
```

Comment: yup, it was just a bitwise operator mistake, now its working fine thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function.
At the end of your code just type ques() and that should call your fucntion and you should be able to get output.

Comment: yup, it was just a bitwise operator mistake, now its working fine thank you :)

Comment: I also tested your code and i think if you make a wrong input when he asks you to multiply it will infinitely print out the output when you make a mistake. Try to find the error if i am corrent(i might be mistaken)

Comment: yup I've just checked it, it is indeed printing indefinitely if the correct answer is not given at first attempt

Comment: i found the mistake. Basically after print('this was incorrect') you need to set finish to true because it only prints out the and remains in the loop. When you make a wrong input it  should print out that you made a mistake and then just set finisht == true  and then when the loop comes again it will be finish == true and it will break the loop.

Comment: can you tell me at which line ?

Comment: basically everywhere where oyu have  print("That's incorrect!,the answer was", realans, "!") you need to put after it finish = True .  I can send you whole code back if you want.

Comment: That would be good help :)

Comment: here i made another Answer so you can get it there test out that code it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


def ques():
    name = input("What's your name?:")
    print("Hi", name, "!")

    choice = random.choice("+x")
    finish = False
    quesno = 0
    correctques = 0

    while finish == False:
        if quesno < 10 | quesno >= 0:
            no1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
            no2 = random.randrange(1, 10)
            print((no1), (choice), (no2))
            ans = int(input("What's the answer?:"))
            quesno = quesno + 1

            if choice == ("+"):
                realans = no1 + no2
                if ans == realans:
                    print("That's the correct answer!")
                    correctques = correctques + 1
                else:
                    print("That's incorrect!,the answer was", realans, "!")
                    finish = True

        if choice == ("x"):
            realans = no1 * no2
            if ans == realans:
                print("That's the correct answer!")
                correctques = correctques + 1
            else:
                print("That's incorrect!,the answer was", realans, "!")
                finish = True

        elif choice == ("-"):
            realans = no1 - no2
            if ans == realans:
                print("That's the correct answer")
                correctques = correctques + 1
            else:
                print("That's incorrect!,the answer was", realans, "!")
                finish = True
        else:
            finish = True
    else:
        print("Good Job", name, "! You have finished the quiz")
ques()
```